# Nginx rewrite with droping part of url

Tags: nginx

I have such url under nginx:
http://localhost:8080/my_backend/test/whatever

which I need to rewrite to
http://dockerized_backend:8081/test/whatever

dockerized_backend is of course from docker-compose, not public

how to do that ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ah simple:

```
location  /my_backend {
          rewrite /my_backend/(.*) /$1  break;
          proxy_pass         http://my_backend:8080;
          proxy_redirect     off;
          proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        }
```